# How to avoid having multiple methods with different arguments for url construction

Tags: java

How to avoid having multiple methods with different arguments for url construction. I would like to optimize this further

```
protected String invUrl() {
    return endpointUrl("invs", null, null);
}   

protected String invUrl(String id) {
    return endpointUrl("invs", id, null);
}   

protected String invUrl(String id, String action) {
    return endpointUrl("invs", id, action);
}   

protected String endpointUrl(String entity, String id, String action) {

    if (id != null && action != null) {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("localhost").port(serverPort)
            .path("/mat/api/v1/" + entity + "/" + id + "/" + action).build().toUriString();
    } else if (id != null) {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("localhost").port(serverPort)
            .path("/mat/api/v1/" + entity + "/" + id).build().toUriString();
    } else {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("localhost").port(serverPort)
            .path("/mat/api/v1/" + entity).build().toUriString();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Instead of sending too many parameters, construct an object in `invUrl` and call `endpointUrl`. You can have only one `invUrl` method with all possible arguments

Comment: No I am looking at something more elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to create an object called `Endpoint` which holds the required values:

```
public class Endpoint {
    private String entity;
    private String id;
    private String action;

    public Endpoint(String entity, String id, String action) {
        this.entity = entity;
        this.id = id;
        this.action = action;
    }

    // getters, toString etc.
}
```

Then you can have only one `invUrl` method to which `id` and `action` can be passed and `Endpoint` object can be constructed. This can be passed to `endpointUrl` method:

```
protected String invUrl(String id, String action) {
        return endpointUrl(new Endpoint("invs", id, action));
    }
```

Then, `endpointUrl` method can be modified as:

```
protected String endpointUrl(Endpoint endpoint) {
        StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder("/mat/api/v1/").append(endpoint.getEntity());
        if(endpoint.getId() != null) {
            pathBuilder.append("/").append(endpoint.getId());
        }
        if(endpoint.getAction() != null) {
            pathBuilder.append("/").append(endpoint.getAction());
        }
        return UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("localhost").port(serverPort)
                .path(pathBuilder.toString()).build().toUriString();
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to add 3 different methods for invUrl, is there a way I can make this as a single method

Comment: Yes @Rpj The solution which I've suggested has only one invUrl method

Comment: there are invocations where it takes no arguments or just id or just id and action. So for the first two cases, I still have to pass null as argument. ruby has mechanisms to default method values to nil if not passed. Is there anything equivalent

Comment: No. Java doesn't support default parameters